# Case statement to render partials in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a page with dynamic content. It's a series of partials that link to each other, and when the user is done they have a full document made up of many partials. I was thinking I could use a case statement with `<%= render 'section1' %>` or something like that, with each partial having its own case statement to create a document of 5 or 6 user-selected partials from a list of 58. However, I don't know how to give rails the input for the case statement. Could I use `form_for` or is there another way to give rails user input to render each partial?

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with this suggestion, but I imagine I'll be adjusting this a little as you respond to this. The form_choices will be the names of each section that you want to include. For my variables, I pictured the sections that would be included in a resume-builder app. I've kind of taught myself to use check box collections like this, so my approach might not be the most conventional. There are ways to use rail's built-in check_box features, but those have been problematic for me when trying to collect a "list of includes".

To follow this example, you'll need to define the "sections_to_include" column in your DynamicPage model so that it can accept an array as its value:

**app/models/dynamic_page.rb**

```
serialize  :sections_to_include
```

**dynamic_page_controller.rb**

```
def new
   @dynamic_page = DynamicPage.new
end

def create
    @dynamic_page = DynamicPage.new(dynamic_page_params)
    if @dynamic_page.save
        redirect_to dynamic_page_path(@dynamic_page)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

    def dynamic_page_params
        params.require(:dynamic_page).permit(sections_to_include: [])
     end
```

**app/views/dynamic_page/new.html.erb**

```
<% form_choices = ["Name", "Contact Info", "Objective", "Work History", "Other Experience", "Skills", "References"] %>

<%= form_for @dynamic_page do %>
    <% form_choices.each_with_index do |c, index| %>
        <input name="dynamic_page[sections_to_include]" type="checkbox" value="<%= index %>" />
        <p><%= c %></p>
    <% end %>

    <%= submit "Build this Page" %>
<% end %>
```

Now the show page iterates through the array that you've defined in the sections_to_include column. For each, it renders a partial that is named section_1, section_2, etc. This will match the id numbers from the check boxes from the previous form.

**app/views/dynamic_page/show.html.erb**

```
<% @dynamic_page.sections_to_include.each do |section_id| %>
    <%= render :partial => "/dynamic_page/section_#{section_id}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Pressing submit in this way, rails is going to look for a post route. If I'm not updating a model, what should the controller do with this information? How should it tell the view to render the partial necessary?

Comment: Now that I think about your question a little more, you probably SHOULD be updating a model. I've added the code that could be used in the controller and the second view. The params might not line up exactly how I'm thinking, because I haven't tested this out. You'll want to do a bit of debugging to see whether the section_to_include column is receiving the type of array that is needed in the next view.